# Can't play this file [.mp4] VideoView android

Tags: android, video

I am trying to create a start screen with video playing in the background . i have a mp4 file named "bday" in raw folder . no error while running the project but at the end a dialog box gives msg "Can't play this file"

**java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    boolean pausing = false;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonPlayVideo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playvideoplayer);

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);

        //Displays a video file.   
        VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);


        String uriPath = "android.resource://com.example.media/"+R.raw.bday;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.start();



        buttonPlayVideo.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    // VideoView refference see main.xml
                    VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);

                    String uriPath = "android.resource://com.android.AndroidVideoPlayer/"+R.raw.bday;

                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
                    mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
                    mVideoView.requestFocus();
                    mVideoView.start();


            }});
     }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String path1 = "";
        if(vid_path!=""||vid_path!=null)
            path1 = "android.resource://com.android.AndroidVideoPlayer/"+R.raw.bday;
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Video path not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         finish();
        }

    final MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
            mc.setAnchorView(video);
            mc.setMediaPlayer(video);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(path1);
            video.setMediaController(mc);
            System.out.println("!-- uri: "+uri.toString());
            video.setVideoURI(uri);

            video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {




                       mProgressDialog.dismiss();






                }
            });

            video.start();

            video.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                }

            });


        }

        public void playVideo(View v) {

        }

        public void showLoaderProgress(){
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading Video\nPlease wait...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }
```

Try the above code.Call the `showLoaderProgress()` after    `VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);`